# How to poke two vectors?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I have a C function like this:

```
double* f(double* input, size_t n, double* result){
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    result[i] = ***something***
  }
  return result;
}
```

I import it in Haskell like this (thanks to [@Zeta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176490/transform-a-vector-with-the-ffi-in-haskell)):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable         as V
import           Foreign
import           Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall unsafe "f" c_f :: Ptr CDouble -> CSize -> Ptr CDouble -> IO (Ptr CDouble)

f :: V.Vector CDouble -> IO (V.Vector CDouble)
f input = do
    fptr <- mallocForeignPtrArray n
    V.unsafeWith input $
      \v -> withForeignPtr fptr $ c_f v (fromIntegral n)
    return $ V.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 fptr n
  where n = V.length input
```

Very nice.

But now I have a function taking two pointers as input:

```
double* f(double* input1, double* input2, size_t n, double* result){
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    result[i] = ***something***
  }
  return result;
}
```

How can I import it to have `f :: V.Vector CDouble -> V.Vector CDouble -> IO (V.Vector CDouble)` ?

Perhaps it's easy but I'm still not comfortable with `withForeignPtr`.

Comment: Why are you using the low level interface and not the higher level `Data.Vector.Storable.generate` and `(!)` (or `unsafeIndex`)?  It isn't necessary to use the pointers manually, we have an API for that.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Sorry I don't see what you mean. Why are you talking about indexing?

Comment: I talk about the API you typically use to construct a vector, that API includes generate and index.  See my answer for a more idiomatic solution that doesn't use pointers explicitly.

Comment: Nevermind, my brain must not be working right - I entirely missed the foreign import of `c_f` and what the actual problem is.   The function you want is likely `generateM` instead.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
f :: V.Vector CDouble -> V.Vector CDouble -> IO (V.Vector CDouble)
f input1 input2 = do
    fptr <- mallocForeignPtrArray n
    V.unsafeWith input1 $ 
      \v1 -> V.unsafeWith input2 $
        \v2 -> withForeignPtr fptr $ c_f v1 v2 (fromIntegral n)
    return $ V.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 fptr n
  where n = V.length input
```